# Android - How to get listed in the share menu?

Tags: android, air, share

I'm creating a messaging app with Air for Android. I would like to enable other apps to share text to my app via the share menu option.

How do I get my app listed in there?

(This is the menu I would like to get listed in:)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an appropriate intent filter in your Activity tag in manifest file.

```
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
       </intent-filter>
```

Your Activity will show up, when Android searches for such Share Intent handlers.

Comment: Thanks, it shows up now but the shared text is missing. I'm using Air 3.5 and the invoke event to get the arguments: `function onAppInvoke(event:InvokeEvent):void {
shared.text = event.arguments.toString()  
 }
` How to get the shared content into my app?

Comment: @Anky Not sure about AIR, but Android apps pass along the text into Intent extras with key : `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT`

Answer (score 1):

To an `Activity` that will handle any shared content, add an `Intent Filter` to your `Manifest`. For example:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />

</intent-filter>
```